# Android : Monitoring folder activity

Tags: android, directory

I want to create an app which would monitor changes to data in a folder on SD card. 
For example if a file is put in a folder, as soon as file is copied, my app would send this file to server and delete this file.
Is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looks like there is no system-wide "FileSystemMonitor" you could connect to.

So you have to write it yourself. You could for example receive the [ACTION_TIME_TICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK) broadcast and check the filesystem for changes yourself every minute using the normal java File classes.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. As per lucky's answer, the android.os.FileObserver class allows monitoring of files and directories.

Comment: You should change the accepted answer to ytw's answer

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use android.os.FileObserver which is available since API Level 1.
Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html